# impixelinfo with value transformation

Tags: matlab

I want to display an image and allow mouse over to show pixel values- as in impixelinfo function.
The thing is- I show the image on an inverse scale (1./image) but want the shown values to be the original ones.
Is there some way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround - puts your original image over the top as a transparent layer, leaving the visible image (1./image) for the user and an invisible image which impixelinfo takes its data from.

```
imshow(1./image);
hold on
h = imshow(image);
set(h, 'AlphaData', zeros(size(image)));
impixelinfo
```